# Cannot create Ubuntu 16.04 startup disk

Tags: startup-disk-creator

Trying to make a USB startup disk with 16.04 I cannot select the inserted DUD of the downloaded 16.04 iso image.  Using the disk creator interface I have an "Other" button that does not allow the selection of the ISO image just browsing within the image down the folder structure with nothing selectable.

On another machine running 14.04 the disk creator app sees the image in the DVD drive and allows selection however this fails to finish the USB image creation showing symptoms of the long outstanding "Failed to install bootloader" bug that it appears will never be fixed.  This bug is more than 4 years old and substantially disables the entire functionality of the disk creator feature.

Is this inability to select a disk in the CD Drive containing the Ubuntu iso image another bug or is there a work-a-round.

For some reason one PC on our network will not boot of the 16.04 ISO disk and all others will however the PC running 16.04 that disk creator will not allow selection of the ISO image will boot of the very same disk.  The PC that will not boot the 16.04 disk will boot from a 14.04 disk so the DVD drive is working and bootable for other disks.

I have frequently seen this before with Ubuntu ISO disks not booting on some machines for no apparent reasons which appears illogical.  The inability to create USB bootable drives is a serious frustrating problem that should be addressed.

Comment: Use `dd` instead.

Answer (score 0):

The Ubuntu Startup Disk Creator in 14.04 LTS is buggy, but the version in 16.04.1 LTS and 16.04.2 LTS is completely different, and works well for me to create USB boot drives from Ubuntu iso files. The old version is an extracting tool, and the new version is a cloning tool.

You can try another tool to create a USB boot drive. If you want a tool that works with all current versions of Ubuntu, 12.04 LTS, 14.04 LTS, 16.04 LTS and 16.10, you can try **mkusb**. It uses the cloning method to create live-only USB drives, and an extracting method to create persistent live USB drives.

**mkusb** can create live-only USB boot drives of most linux iso files (all linux distros that provide hybrid iso files) and also installer USB drives for Windows 7-10. Persistent live drives are limited to Debian and Ubuntu (and some but not all distros and re-spins based on Debian and Ubuntu).

See the following links,

[help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)

[mkUSB-quick-start-manual-12.pdf](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=mkUSB-quick-start-manual-12.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for your advice and assistance, most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool called unetbootin available in the software center. It works well with any Linux distribution.